# How to make the @XmlRootElement as optional

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jaxb2

I have scenario to make a argument to REST API call as an optional.. Below is the scenario in the REST call I will receive a argument passed as `StudentParam` since the name  is an optional is there any way I can make whole argument `StudentParam` as an optional to REST call?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class StudentParam {

    private String name;

    @XmlElement(required=false, name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your REST service head signature?

Comment: You could set a DefaultValue (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) depending on the type of parameter you expect (path, query, matrix,...) Could you state some of your REST service's code?